# How to add validation for field accept number and null? [Laravel 7.x]

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-7, laravel-validation

I want to store the `score` value as a number when `is_pass` is `true`. If `is_pass` is `false` then `score` should be `null`. So I added validation like below for `score`

```
'score' => 'required_if:is_pass,true|numeric'
```

But I have an issue when `is_pass` is `false` then also it's expected `score` value as `numeric`. How to solve this issue? Is there any diffrent option is there other than custom validation? I am using laravel 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a variable to keep you rules.
Then base on condition change your rules.

```php
if((bool) $request->is_pass === true)
    $rules['score'] = 'required_if:is_pass,true|numeric';
else
    $rules['score'] = 'required_if:is_pass,false|null';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It is a useful answer. So I added a vote. But I expect any direct methods. So I didn't accept your answer.

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate it. Hope you find your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nullable` validation with `numeric`  [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-nullable) and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields)

```
'score' => 'nullable|numeric'
```

what this will do is check if the value is not null then apply numeric validation otherwise skip validation and accept it as null.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But It isn't covered my question.